# Installing and using matplotlib on Kivy

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, kivy

I have an issue in trying to use or install matplotlib for Kivy. My aim is to create a plot (and later a scripted plot (I put the cursor and see y and x values)) for financial time series.

What I have done from PyCharm terminal:

```
garden install graph
garden install --upgrade graph
garden install matplotlib
garden install --upgrade matplotlib
```

What my python script import section looks like:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import stock_base
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
```

First PyCharm cannot find FigureCanvasKivyAgg. Moreover if I still try to run the script I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'weight_as_number' from 'matplotlib.font_manager'

I am not very good installing packages manually, as I cannot even find my Python folder, so I resorted to PyCharm, that has worked really well for installing and using many other packages. I use PyCharm also to script and run the script. I have been looking in past stackoverflow questions and around the web, but found no solutions!

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: By default the installation is done in `~/.kivy/garden/`. Please provide the full traceback.